# mPDF how to leave all content on a single page

Tags: php, html, laravel, pdf, mpdf

I want to export an HTML to pdf using mPDF, but I want everything to be on a single page, without any page breaks.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"mPDF has limited scope to control when automatic page-breaks occur, and does not have ‘widows’ or ‘orphans’ protection."

https://mpdf.github.io/paging/page-breaks.html

Comment: I ended up creating a custom page size to fit everything, probably it's not the best practice, but it is working now.
Thanks for the assist!